# Must we wear white clothes?

Tags: halacha, clothing, color, kohelet

Matt wrote here about תפלין‎ (Tefillin)
that "they were all black".

I have also seen jewish men wearing only black.

How do the jews traditionally follow commandment of God (relating to happiness we should have as believers and followers of the Bible) in [Koheleth 9:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3109.htm#8):

> "בְּכָל־עֵ֕ת יִהְי֥וּ בְגָדֶ֖יךָ לְבָנִ֑ים וְשֶׁ֖מֶן עַל־רֹאשְׁךָ֥ אַל־יֶחְסָֽר׃"
>
> "Let thy garments be always white; and let thy head lack no oil."

Are these simply ignored in judaism?

Or are these commandments considered to be replaced by Talmud?

Or is there some kind of interpretation,
that rabbis simply reject the most natural and strong meaning of the word "white"?

And replace it with the meaning "pure" - only?

It cannot be that white colors could be considered unpure,
when Almighty Himself is The Sun and White in the Tehilim.

White should be the most pure of all the colors,
according to Tehilim.

And anyway, according to [David Kimhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kimhi) the great rabbi:

The rule of intepretation of The Bible should be 
the most natural and direct meaning of the word.

And that for that word in Koheleth: "white",
definitely.

According to my simple understanding:
1) Word itself speaks for white colors.
2) Kimhi is for this as a common rule - direct and natural meaning is the best.
3) Context of the word: Koheleth is for white.
3) Tehilim is for white.
4) Also rationality speaks for that: Almighty wants us to be happy,
and white color makes us happy, as number 2) context also gives as argument.

So cumulative argument is very strong
that we should have happy colors and white colors in clothes.

What is the argument from judaism 
to not to accept this doctrine of The Tanakh?

Comment: concerning teffilin only the straps and the ink of the writing need to be black (the boxes themselves can be any color but red)

Comment: you're kidding, right? The "natural" meaning here has nothing to do with colors of clothing

Comment: You talk about "natural meaning" and "meaning in context" .....where, in the context of the [verse in Koheles](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3109.htm#8), do you see that we're discussing teffilin?

Comment: @Shokhet He's not asking specifically about Tefillin

Comment: @DoubleAA His first line implied that he was; on a reread, you're right.

Comment: Thank you for your good question. It would IMHO have been better if you had reduced the power with which your expressed your own views. So I will vote it down.

Comment: A better way to ask the question would be "given the way white clothes are praised, why do orthodox jews tend to dress in primarily black, rather than in white"

Comment: @hazoriz From where do you learn that the tefillin boxes can be any color but red? From what I understand making the tefillin black is a halacha l'Moshe miSinai. ([Shabbat 28b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.28b?lang=bi))

Comment: @ezra is the gemora about the boxes or the straps? And see halacha 4 here http://www.chabad.org/3284479 and halacha 60 here http://chabad.org/3284478/ says you are right

Answer (score 3):

The verse in Ecclesiastes is not one of law and it was explained in a particular way. The basic commentary on the verse (from Rashi who cites the talmud) is

> **At all times, let your garments be white:** Prepare yourself at all times with good deeds, so that if you die today, you will enter in peace. And Solomon likened this to a man whom the king invited for a day of feasting, without setting a time for him. If he is wise or clever, he will immediately launder his garments, and bathe, and anoint himself. So did our Rabbis expound it in Tractate Shabbath ([153a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=153&format=pdf)).

from http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16470#showrashi=true&v=8